# MySQL ORDER BY DESC is fast but ASC is very slow

Tags: mysql, performance

For some reason when I sort this query by DESC it's super fast, but if sorted by ASC it's extremely slow.

This takes about 150 milliseconds:

```
SELECT posts.id
FROM posts USE INDEX (published)
WHERE posts.feed_id IN ( 4953,622,1,1852,4952,76,623,624,10 )
ORDER BY posts.published DESC
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

This takes about 32 seconds:

```
SELECT posts.id
FROM posts USE INDEX (published)
WHERE posts.feed_id IN ( 4953,622,1,1852,4952,76,623,624,10 )
ORDER BY posts.published ASC
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

The EXPLAIN is the same for both queries.

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  posts   index   NULL    published   5   NULL    50  Using where
```

I've tracked it down to "USE INDEX (published)". If I take that out it's the same performance both ways. But the EXPLAIN shows the query is less efficient overall.

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  posts   range   feed_id feed_id 4   \N  759 Using where; Using filesort
```

And here's the table.

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feed_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `content` blob,
  `author` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `published` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `post_url` (`post_url`,`feed_id`),
  KEY `feed_id` (`feed_id`),
  KEY `published` (`published`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=196530 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your index is sorted desc so when you ask for ascending it needs to do a lot more work to bring it back in that order

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there a fix for this? I'm thinking about using 2 different queries, this one for DESC and a different one for ASC.

Comment: If you are using mysql 5+ you should be able to define multiple indexes.

Comment: From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html :

An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These keywords are allowed for future extensions for specifying ascending or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order.


So, how can I create an index that is sorted desc ?

Comment: @SQLMenace Why couldn't a desc index simply return results "upside-down". I don't see why a desc index and an asc index are not identical, can you explain why?

Comment: I don't see how the accepted answer actually answers the question. Pepper states that his SELECT with `ORDER BY DESC` is *faster* than `ORDER BY ASC`, yet indexes are always sorted in ASC order. Why, then, isn't `ORDER BY DESC` slower?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't suggest you create another index on the table; every time a row is inserted or deleted, each index on the table needs to be updated, slowing down `INSERT` queries.

The index is definitely what's slowing it down. Maybe you could try `IGNORE`-ing it:

```
SELECT posts.id
FROM posts IGNORE INDEX (published)
WHERE posts.feed_id IN ( 4953,622,1,1852,4952,76,623,624,10 )
ORDER BY posts.published ASC
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

Or, since the field is already `KEY`ed, you might try the following:

```
SELECT posts.id
FROM posts USE KEY (published)
WHERE posts.feed_id IN ( 4953,622,1,1852,4952,76,623,624,10 )
ORDER BY posts.published ASC
LIMIT 0, 50;
```

Comment: Thanks, USE KEY and USE INDEX seem to have the same result. And not using USE INDEX has the same result as IGNORE INDEX.

Answer (score 3):

You could get your data set first, and then order it.

Something like

```
SELECT posts.id FROM (
SELECT posts.id
FROM posts USE INDEX (published)
WHERE posts.feed_id IN ( 4953,622,1,1852,4952,76,623,624,10 )
LIMIT 0, 50
)
order by postS.id ASC;
```

It should first use the index to find all records that satisfy your "where" statement, and the will order them. But the order would be performed in a smaller set. Give it a try and then tell us.

Best Regards.

Comment: It actually works for me. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about flipping the WHERE condition?

```
SELECT posts.id
FROM posts USE INDEX (published)
WHERE posts.feed_id IN ( 10,624,623,76,4952,1852,622,4953 )
ORDER BY posts.published DESC;
```

Comment: I don't understand, can you clarify or provide an example?

Comment: SELECT posts.id
FROM posts USE INDEX (published)
WHERE posts.feed_id IN ( 10,624,623,76,4952,1852,622,4953 )
ORDER BY posts.published DESC;

well ... post.created should have the exact same sorting

Answer (score 0):

You want to add an index across (feed_id, published):

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD INDEX (feed_id, published)
```

That'll make this query run best, and you won't need to force a particular index with USE INDEX.

Comment: This is what I had before, but on a table of 500000+ entries it was performing slowly. Forcing the index on published above is about 3x faster when ordered by DESC and 10x slower when ordered by ASC

Comment: You tried this exact index?  In that order?  Define "slowly". 500,000+ rows is really not a big deal to MySQL (unless your server is ancient), and with an index across those two fields, this query should be all-index regardless of sort direction.  That "Using filesort" in your one explain plan should tip you off - there's no reason that should happen when optimizing simple one-table queries like this.

Also, what is "published"?  Is there a good reason it's an int(12)?

Comment: I guess by "slowly" i mean slower than what I have with DESC sorting. It's doing a type: range, hitting 4000 rows instead of 50 and is using filesort.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, I just tried it myself and saw what you reported. Apparently I'm no help on this.  Just when you think you understand MySQL query optimization... :\

Comment: heh it's ok :) your answer is what I started with, and should be the best way to do it... sadly the results aren't as expected.