# optimizing less than greater than query of mysql

Tags: mysql

i am facing heavy load from my one query . i have 10 million data in my table and i have done indexing of both pid and fid columns then also mysql explain shows that it is not using any index

here is my query

```
    select * from tableA where pid < '94898' and fid='37' order by id desc limit 1;
```

my mysql explain output says this

```
         id     select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra 
         1      SIMPLE  tableA  index   fid     PRIMARY     4   NULL    152     Using where
```

but mysql slow shows its scanning millions of data