# sort by descending order taking much time to load in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, sorting, sql-order-by, load-time

I have one table with 33,107,887  records.

table structure: tablename

```
id - bigint - uniqu
text - text - fulltex index
cate_id - bigint - btree index
marchant_name - varchare - btree index
created_on - timestamp - btree index
```

When i run below query then its takeing 60+ seconds

```
SELECT * FROM tablename where marchant_name='marchant name x' order by id  desc limit 20
```

but if i run this query then its take just 1 second

```
SELECT * FROM tablename where marchant_name='marchant name x' order by id  asc limit 20
```

Note : Here marchant name x has 8mn+ records in main table.

Hear just issue with "oder by asc" and "order by desc" . Is there anyone who can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the results of `EXPLAIN` for both queries? Also, is there index for `(merchant_name, id)` created?

Comment: both query are same just their order by different. like,

order by id  desc limit 20 and order by id  asc limit 20

Comment: It's quite clear from the original post. What I'm asking for is that you add the results of running `EXPLAIN` on both queries to it - as it might be hinting on why's the difference that drastic. Also note that two separate indexes on two columns are not the same as composite index for two columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ORDER BY DESC is fast but ASC is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886575/mysql-order-by-desc-is-fast-but-asc-is-very-slow)